# How much of my code is still around?

Tags: git, github

Strange question, but a pretty reasonable one I think. Basically there's a project that I started several years ago with a couple hundred lines of code. Amazingly, since then it's grown to be a huge, robust project that I'm very proud of.

Now, I have a question that very often pops into my head:

> How much of my code is still around?

Almost certainly the vast majority of my code has been rewritten at this point, but it feels like it should be very possible to have git give me a picture of what's still around.

Now, I've looked into this on a basic level, but can't really find anything else along these lines, though some of github's charts are helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for reports of your code that haven't been modified since the project began?

Comment: @RobbieAverill that sounds right. Any line of code I wrote that hasn't been changed since I wrote it.

Comment: If you interested in how many lines of your code is unchaged, then you can just use blame to calculate it over time.

Comment: `git blame` should tell you that story on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: @JosephSilber Seems to be a reasonable start, still figuring out the docs, but will definitely accept an answer that comes with this and a little bash niceness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) is a way to go. Here is how you can calculate number of lines which was changed by each author in current revision

```sh
git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only \
    | xargs -I{} git blame --line-porcelain {} \
    | sed -n 's/^author //p' \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -rn
```

Which will give

```
15492 Alice
 3406 Bob
  100 Carol
```

Comment: But note that *any* change to a line of code (formatting, changing spaces to tabs or vice versa, etc.) will hide the original author.

Comment: @KeithThompson unfortunately yes. Actually this might be not a direct answer to a question since this is a count of lines _'touched'_ by each author.

Comment: @KeithThompson _(aside)_ actually this is a very philosophical question of how patches affects _'ownership' of code_ :D